# Cypress automation - control with pseudo css selector is always present in style

Tags: html, css, automation, css-selectors, cypress

I have a custom checkbox control with a psuedo css selector.

Following is the html before checking the checkbox:
[image]

Following is the html after checking the checkbox
[image]

I want to know wether the control is checked or not.
I don’t seem to get anything unique regarding the state. Even the pseudo selector is always present in style no matter the state of the checkbox.

Can some one help me get the state of checkbox ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below to check whether the checkbox is checked or not.

To check whether the checkbox is checked:

```
cy.get(selector).should('be.checked')
```

To check whether the checkbox is not checked:

```
cy.get(selector).should('not.be.checked')
```

Comment: but this is a custom control And not a checkbox. The be.checked works for custom controls as well ?

Comment: Can you try once. I can see that the input type is checkbox.

Comment: it worked with the checkbox locator. I was trying to check, uncheck on the span locator with the long cut method of evaluating the css property. Thank you so much!